# Youtube gdata java api ParseException

Tags: java, youtube, gdata, parseexception

I'm trying to make some search using youtube gdata api for java but i'm having some errors.

I set max. result to 20 and started to make test searches and occasionally there is no result back.

Then i started to make one by one searches and i noticed that some single search results have problems and when i set max. results to 20, there is no result back even one result has a problem.

Stack trace is:

```
Haz 29, 2012 2:45:40 PM com.wattalist.gdata.youtube.GdataYoutube Search
SEVERE: null
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 101152, element yt:state] Invalid value for attribute : 'name'
at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.throwParseException(XmlParser.java:739)
at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:702)
at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:585)
at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:867)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178)
at com.wattalist.gdata.youtube.GdataYoutube.Search(GdataYoutube.java:47)
at com.wattalist.servlets.PlayerAjaxServlet.writeSearchResults(PlayerAjaxServlet.java:137)
at com.wattalist.servlets.PlayerAjaxServlet.doPost(PlayerAjaxServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Invalid value for attribute : 'name'
at com.google.gdata.data.AttributeHelper.consumeEnum(AttributeHelper.java:592)
at com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YtPublicationState.consumeAttributes(YtPublicationState.java:184)
at com.google.gdata.data.AbstractExtension$AttributesHandler.processEndElement(AbstractExtension.java:263)
at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.endElement(XmlParser.java:1013)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.endElement(ParserAdapter.java:650)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:598)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.parse(ParserAdapter.java:429)
at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:694)
... 39 more
```

i made some research about it i noticed that in older versions of gdata youtbe api there was this problem but can be solved with a workaround like this:

> A temporary fix would be to copy the source for
>   com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YtPublicationState and add restricted type like below.
>    Then adding it higher in the classpath.
>   public static enum State {

```
/**
 * The video has not been completely defined yet, but it's been stored
 * already.
 * Either the video data or the description is missing.
 */
INCOMPLETE,

/** The video has just been uploaded and is not yet publicly available. */
PROCESSING,

/** The video has been rejected. */
REJECTED,

/** The video was not successfully processed. */
FAILED,

/** Video was removed by the owner. */
DELETED,

RESTRICTED,
;
```

}

But i'm using the latest version gdata-src.java-1.47.1 version. 
i have the jars:

gdata-core-1.0.jar

gdata-youtube-2.0.jar

gdata-youtube-meta-2.0.jar

gdata-client-1.0.jar

gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar

gdata-media-1.0.jar

guava-11.0.2.jar
jsr305.jar

mail.jar

i checked the YtPublicationState in the source code and the enum State has RESTRICTED element.

but i still get the exception.

The source code i'm getting the exception is:

```
public VideoFeed Search(String criteria, int maxResults, int startIndex)
{
    try
    {
        YouTubeQuery youtubeQuery = new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));

        youtubeQuery.setFullTextQuery(criteria);
        youtubeQuery.setMaxResults(_maxResults);
        youtubeQuery.setStartIndex(_startIndex);

        VideoFeed videoFeed = _youtubeService.query(youtubeQuery, VideoFeed.class);

        return videoFeed;
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(GdataYoutube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(GdataYoutube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

anyone knows how to fix it or any alternative?
(i thougt of getting the results one by one and eliminate the broken result on my own on the server but it will have so much communication overheads.)

Comment: may be attaching source code to tha gdata jars and debugging may be a little step.

Comment: Can anybody give some help about how can i attach the source code to jar for debugging?